# A simple yet confusing puzzle - Fake money involved!

Tags: puzzle

A very simple but confusing puzzle.A lady buys goods worth rs.200 from a shop.(Shopkeeper selling the goods with zero profit).The lady gives him 1000 rs note. The shopkeeper gets the change from the next shop and keeps 200 for himself and returns rs.800 to d lady.Later the shopkeeper of the next shop comes with the 1000rs note saying"duplicate" and takes his money back.How much LOSS did the shopkeeper face?

Edit:

Generally concieved answer is 1000rs. But should we not consider the loss from counterfeit currency. If that would be considered as loss then the answer would be 2000. is it not?